# javascript node command line debugging

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, command-line-interface

- I'm trying to debug javascript code with `node inspect` on terminal
- I can step through, and set breakpoints, but can *not* inspect values
- For instance, I get an error when I try to print `i` below:

```bash
$ npx tsc --strict main.ts # <--- compiled from typescript
$ node inspect ./main.js   # <--- run with node inspect
< Debugger listening on < ... omitted ... >
< For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
< 
< Debugger attached.
< 
 ok
Break on start in main.js:12
 10     return true;
 11 }
>12 console.log(isPrime(8));
 13 
debug> sb(6)
  1 "use strict";
  2 function isPrime(p) {
  3     for (var i = 2; i < p; i++) {
  4         for (var j = 2; j < p; j++) {
  5             if (i * j === p) {
> 6                 return false;
  7             }
  8         }
  9     }
 10     return true;
 11 }
```

Here is the error message I get in the terminal:

```bash
debug> console.log(i)
REPL2:1
console.log(i)
            ^

Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
    at REPL2:1:13
    at Script.runInContext (node:vm:141:12)
    ... omitted for brevity ...
```

Comment: I think you're supposed to do something like `p "i"` to print the value of an expression in the current debug context.

Comment: [Documentation](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v18.x/docs/api/debugger.html#stepping)

Comment: `watch(i)` gives the exact same error ...

Comment: What about `watch("i")`?

Comment: The documentation is inadequate, but it appears that expressions must be passed as strings. All the examples use single quotes, so `exec('i')` or `p 'i'` or `watch('i')`.